# How can I use SQL MERGE to upsert single row based on Id, without a source set

Tags: sql-server, merge, sql-server-2008-r2

There are a number of questions on the proper use of the `MERGE` statement in SQL Server. They all use a table/set reference for the merge. Is this table reference necessary?

In my case I have a sproc with two parameters `@myId` and `@myValue`

I simply want an UPSERT into `MyTable` based on the column `[MyId]`

It seems strange that I would have to create a set with

```
USING (SELECT @myId AS myId) AS source
```

to proceed with the `MERGE` (upsert). Is this the only way?

**EDIT:** voted to close my own question as exact duplicated... but I think the other question's title made it difficult to find.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need merge for this use case? What does it buy you, except that the syntax is very hard to construct (as you've found), it doesn't buy you any more concurrency / race condition protection than old-style upsert (unless you add specific locking hints), and there are multiple unresolved bugs with merge? `UPDATE / IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 / INSERT` is much easier to write, maintain, and understand. IMHO.

Comment: (PS that is not just lip service. In [this blog post, I highlight 12 still unresolved MERGE bugs](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/02/t-sql-queries/another-merge-bug), and in [this blog post, Dan Guzman shows how MERGE on its own does not protect you from race conditions](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Perhaps I will have to research this more, but my understanding was that `MERGE` in sprocs is faster to process than `UPDATE / IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 / INSERT` ... Both links you provide are good, though neither apply to my particular use case.

Comment: I'd love to see some performance metrics that back that up. Just because it *looks* like it should be faster doesn't mean that it is. Deep down in the engine, it has to do the exact same thing that you're doing in slightly more verbose (but certainly more understandable and predictable) ways.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have to yield to your expertise on the subject, but suffice to say that there are other SQL professionals who have been advocating the `MERGE` function (perhaps they are not aware of the limitations you've discovered).

Comment: Can you point to some real links where SQL professionals have advocated MERGE *for performance reasons*?

Comment: Also, you can quite easily test the performance yourself, using your statements and your data on your hardware. I'd be interested to see if your observations match your understanding. :-)

Comment: All the articles I'm finding are explicitly about `MERGE`ing larger sets, not single rows as I have done here.

Comment: but yet you are saying you want to use MERGE on your single row operation because it is faster? I'm confused.

Comment: I guess I'm saying that I was wrong and that the basis of my intent to do this was poorly founded :D

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this syntax:

```
merge into MyTable mt
using (values (@myId, @myValue)) t(id, value) on mt.Id = t.id
when not matched then insert /* ... */
```

You're always going to need a set of some kind.